# How to Lazy loading form content of Angular Material Stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

The angular documentation says

> Lazy rendering
>
> By default, the stepper will render all of it's content when it's
> initialized. If you have some content that you want to defer until the
> particular step is opened, you can put it inside an **ng-template** with
> the **matStepContent** attribute.

The angular example given is very simple - uses paragraph etc

How to do it for a UI that has ngFor , and Form? i.e. a bit complex

See the below stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmk1qz?file=src/app/app.component.html

It doesnt work, if I uncomment

```
<!-- <ng-template matStepContent> --> and the ending  <!-- </ng-template> -->
```

Can someone help me on getting that stackblitz lazy loaded/rendered

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzyhew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-lazy-content-example.html) how to achieve this, it does not have exactly the `formly-form` component but it has a representation of an `ngFor` using a `form` as a parent with lazy rendered steps.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it didn't work in my model. I even commented form tags..still no luck

Comment: Note: I dont need the top level form. <!-- <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()"> --> .  I want to get my stackblitz working